# Is there a way save with cron?

Tags: bash, cron

Is there a cron command that go into a specific App and save?

Or, another way around, how to save an App with a bash script? (and run the script with cron).

Running OS 10.11

Comment: Which application specifically? A solution will require calling an  AppleScript snippet from bash, so it only works for Applications supporting AS

Comment: POEdit. I went to AppleScript Editor > Open Dictionary, but that App was not available.